# which flavor of Ubuntu works on ASUS P4GE MX mobo with P4 and 1gb ram

Tags: unity

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed on ASUS P4GE MX Mother board with Intel 845 Chip set and Pentium 4 processor with 1GB ram.

Unity and Dash are not loaded, hence not able to close any page opened by  right clicking on blank desktop and entering into 'change desktop background'. Live wall papers are working but the setting page is not closing as no buttons are available on the panel.

I removed Ubuntu 13.10 and tried with 13.04 / 12.10 / 12.04 / 11.10 and 11.04.

Ubuntu 11.04 is working but the problem is that it out of date and upgrades available.

Please provide a way / solution

Comment: I'd suggest you give Lubuntu 13.10 or Xubuntu 12.04 a try.  They will run on older machines. Take a look at this question: [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/q/206407/107450)

Answer (score 0):

Because your system is a lower-end machine try the **latest version of Lubuntu**. This is the best option, in my opinion, as it runs on very minimal resources.